# UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions adds odd opacity

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I created an extension to `UIImage` and added the function `imageWithColor(color: UIColor)` that goes like this:

```
func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, size.height)
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Normal)

    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size)
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, CGImage)
    color.setFill()
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

The problem is that when I display the image (using an `UIImageView`) it's being displayed with an odd opacity (like alpha 0.5 or something) and I can't understand why.

Any ideas why is it happening?

Comment: The obvious answer is that `CGImage` is full of 0.5. Are you sure that's not the case? What is in `CGImage`?

Comment: @robmayoff What do you mean? What should I change?

Comment: What is in `CGImage`? What is `color`?

Comment: @robmayoff I don't have a variable named `CGImage`, and `color` is `UIColor.redColor()`

Comment: Look at the third parameter of the call to `CGContextClipToMask` in your question. It says `CGImage`.

Comment: @robmayoff That's the `UIImage` property (returns a `CGImage` of the `UIImage`)

Comment: OK, so maybe your `UIImage` is full of pixels with value 0.5. Are you sure that's not the case? Also, try writing your resulting image to a PNG file and checking it with an image editor. Does it look correct?